# "Simple" SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Each of my clients can have many todo items and every todo item has a due date.

What would be the query for discovering the next undone todo item by due date for each file?  In the event that a client has more than one todo, the one with the lowest id is the correct one.

Assuming the following minimal schema:

```
clients (id, name)

todos (id, client_id, description, timestamp_due, timestamp_completed)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't said which platform you're using - different platforms have different syntaxes.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server, but I left it out on purpose.  I'd prefer a straight SQL solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this yet, so you may have to tweak it:

```
SELECT
    TD1.client_id,
    TD1.id,
    TD1.description,
    TD1.timestamp_due
FROM
    Todos TD1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Todos TD2 ON
    TD2.client_id = TD1.client_id AND
    TD2.timestamp_completed IS NULL AND
    (
        TD2.timestamp_due < TD1.timestamp_due OR
        (TD2.timestamp_due = TD1.timestamp_due AND TD2.id < TD1.id)
    )
WHERE
    TD2.id IS NULL
```

Instead of trying to sort and aggregate, you're basically answering the question, "Is there any other todo that would come before this one?" (based on your definition of "before"). If not, then this is the one that you want.

This should be valid on most SQL platforms.

Comment: This is my favorite solution to this sort of problem.  I've posted it on SO and other newsgroups many times.  It uses no subquery, no GROUP BY, and no vendor-proprietary syntax.

Answer (score 3):

This question is the classic ***pick-a-winner for each group***.  It gets posted about twice a day.

```
SELECT *
FROM todos t
WHERE t.timestamp_completed is null
  and
(
  SELECT top 1 t2.id
  FROM todos t2
  WHERE t.client_id = t2.client_id
    and t2.timestamp_completed is null
     --there is no earlier record
    and
    (t.timestamp_due > t2.timestamp_due
       or (t.timestamp_due = t2.timestamp_due and t.id > t2.id)
    )
) is null
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.name, MIN(t.id)
FROM clients c, todos t
WHERE c.id = t.client_id AND t.timestamp_complete IS NULL
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING t.timestamp_due <= MIN(t.timestamp_due)
```

Avoids a subquery, correlated or otherwise but introduces a bunch of aggregate operations which aren't much better.

Comment: Using sqlite syntax, but there's nothing special.

Comment: This wouldn't work in SQL Server, as the group by doesn't contain the Name and Description columns.

Comment: This assumes that the ids represent chronology, and they don't.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for lowest id.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for the lowest id in the case of a tied date.

Comment: Having -before- group by?  Wierd stuff.

Comment: *forhead slap* That's what I get for just copying just the HAVING line instead of the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

Some Jet SQL, I realize it is unlikely that the questioner is using Jet, however the reader may be.

```
SELECT c.name, t.description, t.timestamp_due
FROM (clients c 
      INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT t.client_id, Min(t.id) AS MinOfid
          FROM todos t
          WHERE t.timestamp_completed Is Null
          GROUP BY t.client_id) AS tm 
ON c.id = tm.client_id) 
INNER JOIN todos t ON tm.MinOfid = t.id
```

Answer (score -1):

The following should get you close, first get the min time for each client, then lookup the client/todo information

```
SELECT
    C.Id,
    C.Name,
    T.Id
    T.Description,
    T.timestamp_due
FROM
{
    SELECT
        client_id,
        MIN(timestamp_due) AS "DueDate"
    FROM todos
    WHERE timestamp_completed IS NULL
    GROUP BY ClientId
} AS MinValues
    INNER JOIN Clients C
    ON (MinValues.client_id = C.Id)
    INNER JOIN todos T
    ON (MinValues.client_id = T.client_id
        AND MinValues.DueDate = T.timestamp_due)
ORDER BY C.Name
```

**NOTE:** Written assuming SQL Server