# What SQL query or LINQ code would get the following data?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

First, here is a picture of the relevant part of my database schema:

[Database Schema http://ewal.net/stuff/schema.png](http://ewal.net/stuff/schema.png)

I have several conceptual queries of increasing complexity.  Currently, I am doing these with a series of SQL queries (i.e. many back-and-forth trips from the C# code to the SQL Server), and I'd like to find a way to get these each in a single query, but doing so is a bit beyond my personal TSQL/LINQ abilities.  Here are the queries I am trying to figure out how to write:

1. A query to return most recent workplan record for each user (not for a particular user--for all users).
2. A query to return the most recent workplan for each of a specified set of users (i.e. I have a list of userids on the client (i.e. in an array)
3. A query to retrieve all of the "current" project records for each of a specified set of users.  "Current" means the workplan record that the project is attached to is the most recent workplan record for the associated user.

For reference, I am using SQL Server 2005 and LINQ to SQL in C# and would be happy to find either a stored procedure-based solution or direct LINQ code that accomplishes each query.

Comment: Define "most recent".  Is it simply the WorkPlan with the largest date, or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246870/simple-sql-query/246934#246934

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most recent work plan for all users:

```
SELECT
     WP1.*
FROM
     Workplans WP1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Workplans WP2 ON
     WP2.UserID = WP1.UserID AND
     WP2.Date > WP1.Date
WHERE
     WP2.WorkplanID IS NULL
```

For a given set of users, write a table-valued function that turns a delimited list of IDs into a table of those IDs. If you search around I know I've posted that code on here before. Then you can use:

```
SELECT
     WP1.*
FROM
     dbo.GetTableFromIDList(@id_list) U
INNER JOIN Workplans WP1 ON
     WP1.UserID = U.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Workplans WP2 ON
     WP2.UserID = WP1.UserID AND
     WP2.Date > WP1.Date
WHERE
     WP2.WorkplanID IS NULL
```

For a given set of users, return all of their current projects:

```
SELECT
     P.*
FROM
     dbo.GetTableFromIDList(@id_list) U
INNER JOIN Workplans WP1 ON
     WP1.UserID = U.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Workplans WP2 ON
     WP2.UserID = WP1.UserID AND
     WP2.Date > WP1.Date
INNER JOIN dbo.Projects P ON
     P.WorkplanID = WP1.WorkplanID
WHERE
     WP2.WorkplanID IS NULL
```

Of course, you should actually list out the column names instead of using "*".